# If expression with question mark. What does it translate to with a normal if else instruction

Tags: if-statement, logic

I have this expression which I know is an if statement...but what does it translate to?
flag = flag?0:1;
Is it : if (flag==flag) flag=0 else flag =1
if this is the case then flag will become 1 once when timer reaches 12500 but it will never become 0 again. right?

```
int flag = 0; 
while(1)
  {
     if (timer == 12500)
       {
          flag = flag?0:1;
          timer=0;
       }

     if(flag == 1)

      p4_0=0; //turn on LED0

    else

      p4_0=1; //turn off LED0

    timer++;
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Paul, you should accept answers if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

that is a ternary expression

var = var ? expression1 : expression2

means if var is truthy, assign expression1 to var, else assign expression2 to var. basically this.

```
if (var)
    var = expression1
else
    var = expression2
```

so in the code you have above, when the timer == 12500, the flag will be reset and turn off LED0.

Answer (score 1):

(flag = flag?0:1) means that if(flag) then flag=0 otherwise flag=1.To be more precise,if the value of flag is 0 then flag will become 1 otherwise for all non-zero value flag will become 0. Its use in your code is that as soon as the timer reaches 12500 the flag will become 1 and the LED will be turned on and it will remain ON henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

flag = flag?0:1;
Means if flag is 0 then it is zero, if flag >0, then flag becomes 1.